# MongoDB text search logical AND

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, text-search

MongoDB seems to only do logical OR text queries?

If I want to find all documents that contain the words ('apple' or 'orange' or 'pear') I can do the following.

```
db.collection.runCommand('text', {search: 'apple orange pear', limit: -1})
```

But how do I find all documents that contain all 3 of the words ('apple' and 'orange' and 'pear') in no particular order.

Is this possible?

Comment: Check this answer out as a workaround for supporting logical `AND` queries by wrapping each single search term with double quotes:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35641331/1123355

Answer (score 5):

Logical AND operation can be done like this

"\"word1\" \"word2\""

in your example, hence: 
"\"apple\" \"orange" \"pear""

Comment: this is not working at present, means it is returning All apple and all orange records    db.getCollection('myCollection').find({"$text" :{ "$search" : "\"apple\" \"orange\" " }}), can u help me.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible to do that. Please refer the documentation here - 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/#match-phrases

For your query it should look something like this...

```
db.collection.runCommand('text', { search : "('apple') AND ('orange') AND
                                             ('pear')", limit : 1 });
```

Comment: I don't think that is right, you link is right but you have taken the explanation example and not the code example

Comment: @Sammaye, i didn't get you.. are you saying the code above is wrong?, i tested it did work in my db...

Comment: Are you totally sure or did it just search in a different way? Read the entire seciton you will see what I mean

Comment: yes i am sure... for IP reasons i couldn't put the queries i tried in my application. Each time i searched it gave me results matching all the strings.. Let me know if you finding any issues?

Comment: Would by any chance also give results match any of the strings? Unless the `'` are the same as `"` when translated

Comment: To make it easier, the answer your looking for is: `"\"apple\" \"orange\" \"pear\""`

Comment: Sammaye you are correct. The text command performs a compound logical AND of phrases. Where the syntax for a phase is \"phrase\".

Comment: @CathalCoffey would you mind pasting the final(solved) query here... it will help..